# Non-trivial characters of $SU(2)$

Tags: representation-theory, characters

Are there non-trivial characters (or quasi-characters) of the special unitary group $SU(2)$?
I couldn't find a straightforward answer by googling.

Comment: By a character do you mean a homomorphism to $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$? If so, then no.

Comment: Yes, I am talking about homomorphisms into $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$. Can you give an idea of how one proves this?

Comment: There are lots of things you could do depending on your level of sophistication. You could try to show explicitly that $SU(2)$ has trivial abelianization by writing every element as a product of commutators. Or you could use any number of methods to more generally classify the irreducible representations of $SU(2)$ (this is classical and important) and check that there's only one $1$-dimensional irrep.